Not able to execute Karate Framework UI Test Cases over GitLab pipeline, seeing connection refused
Execution Logs:
09:25:41.562 org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9222 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused, http call failed after 2 milliseconds for url: http://localhost:9222/json
09:25:41.566 driver config / start failed: http call failed after 2 milliseconds for url: http://localhost:9222/json
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9222 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused, options: {type=chrome, showDriverLog=true, target=null}
09:25:41.567 src/test/java/com/fiserv/cp/dataaggregator/features/RetrievalUIFlowAllDataSessionID.feature:17
Given driver FIAccountWebURL
driver config / start failed: http call failed after 2 milliseconds for url: http://localhost:9222/json
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9222 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused, options: {type=chrome, showDriverLog=true, target=null}
src/test/java/com/fiserv/cp/dataaggregator/features/RetrievalUIFlowAllDataSessionID.feature:17
.gitlab.yml file:
variables:
  DOC: na/gbs/carat-digital-ecommerce/clx
  http_proxy: "http://fdcproxy.1dc.com:8080"
  https_proxy: "http://fdcproxy.1dc.com:8080"
  image: "fmk-prod.nexus-ci.onefiserv.net/apm/0001171/fmk-datavas-openjdk-17-chrome125:8f2a9544"
  SOURCE_NEXUS_REGISTRY: "fmk.nexus.onefiserv.net"
  DESTINATION_NEXUS: "fmk.nexus-ci.onefiserv.net"
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Djava.awt.headless=true"
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version -DinstallAtEnd=true -DdeployAtEnd=true"
  REGISTRY: "https://fmk.nexus.onefiserv.net/repository/npm-group/"

stages:
  - test
  - report


please read the guidelines and improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

please take look now.

I hope someone else here helps - but from the error it looks like a very basic mistake where your URLs for the test are configured wrong. I suggest you take the help of the wider team. you can search other answers, and maybe the gitlab box does not have HTTP access to the server you want to test: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+gitlab
